# Earth wiring in an AC circuit

Tags: circuit-design, ground, earth

In this circuit there is a power supply source of main AC 220 V - 50 Hz and a load:

[image]

There are two wires out of the main supply (neutral) and (live).

The earth is connected to the neutral.

If I am making a circuit like this, how do I connect the neutral to earth?

Do connect earth to neutral so the neutral will be 0 volt like the earth?

Answer (score 3):

You do not connect neutral to earth. That is done for you at some point at or before the distribution panel, if it is permitted or required in your area, and will always be done at the last transformer before you in the distribution system.

If you are wiring up a mains connected device, you connect only the live and neutral wires to the 'current consuming' terminals of the device.

The earth gets connected to the earth bond point on the device, if it exists, which is connected to any conductive exposed areas of it. Some mains powered devices are double insulated (indicated by two concentric squares) which means they do not need an earth connection for safety.

The earth is intended to carry current only in the case of a fault, it should not be used to carry current intentionally.

Comment: So voltage in neutral always is 0 voltage

Comment: @Tito Nominally zero, though it can be as much as a few volts, depending on how far back in the system the connection is made, and how much current is flowing in the neutral conductor between you and that tie point. You can be assured though that the E-N potential is orders of magnitude less than the E-L potential.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific country you're in, there may be regulations on how to connect things.

The "earth" is usually "protective earth" and is typically intended to connect to a chassis, so that if a fault connects a live conductor to the chassis, it will open a breaker rather than make the chassis live and a shock hazard.  If the end equipment is "double insulated" then a protective earth may not be necessary.

Protective earth is often connected to neutral at the service entrance to the building, but regulations vary.

If your circuit has a metal box around it, connect the protective earth to the box.  If it's double insulated you may not need to use the protective earth conductor.

However, when working with mains voltages you should consult your local electrical code and a qualified electrician if you have any doubts at all.